# Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'IZsCustomerApi'

Tags: c#

I am using a Nuget package to talk to the Zoho CRM API.

There is an interface that looks like this:

```
namespace Teference.Zoho.Api
{
public interface IZsCustomerApi
{
    Task<ZsCustomer> CreateAsync(ZsCustomerInput createInput);
    Task<ZsCustomer> CreateAsync(string apiBaseUrl, string authToken, string organizationId, ZsCustomerInput createInput);
    Task<bool> DeleteAsync(string id);
    Task<bool> DeleteAsync(string apiBaseUrl, string authToken, string organizationId, string id);
    Task<ZsCustomers> GetAllAsync(QueryStringBuilder queryStringBuilder = null);
    Task<ZsCustomers> GetAllAsync(string apiBaseUrl, string authToken, string organizationId, QueryStringBuilder queryStringBuilder = null);
    Task<ZsCustomer> GetAsync(string id);
    Task<ZsCustomer> GetAsync(string apiBaseUrl, string authToken, string organizationId, string id);
    Task<ZsCustomer> UpdateAsync(string id, ZsCustomerInput updateInput);
    Task<ZsCustomer> UpdateAsync(string apiBaseUrl, string authToken, string organizationId, string id, ZsCustomerInput updateInput);
}
}
```

I want to call the "GetAllAsync" function.

I have tried to instantiate the interface like this:

```
IZsCustomerApi customerAPI = new IZsCustomerApi();
```

But I get the error

> Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'IZsCustomerApi'

I am missing something obvious but cannot work out what?

Comment: You cannot instantiate an abstract class or an interface. You need a concrete type (class).

Comment: So basically you are looking for this one:  `public class Foo : IZsCustomerApi`, or a factory, IOC container that does the creation/resolving for you.

Comment: You would expect to find something already in the nugget package?

Comment: Probably there is. What's the nuget-package's name?

Comment: I think I need to use this? https://github.com/teference/zoho-dotnet/blob/master/source/Zoho.Api/Impl/ZsCustomerApi.cs

Comment: Unlikely since it is internal, what is the nu-get package name?

Comment: https://github.com/teference/zoho-dotnet

Comment: var client = new ZohoClient(); var customerApi = client.Subscription.Customers; thats it

Comment: Jep, @SirRufo; that's the one